# Not able to read json data using AngularJS $http control

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, single-page-application

I have a very simple program that reads data from a JSON file (data.txt) located in the same folder as the HTML file. But the program fails to read this file and here is the browser output that gets generated.

**Browser Output**

```
Name                  Roll No                 Percentage
{{ student.Name}}   {{ student.RollNo}}     {{ student.Percentage}}
```

**Main.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS Ajax</title>
        <style>
            table, th , td {
                border: 1px solid grey;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(odd) {
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
            mainApp.controller('studentController', function ($scope, $http) {
                var url = "data.txt";
                $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
                    $scope.students = response;
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>AngularJS Ajax</h2>
        <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="studentController">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Roll No</th>
                    <th>Percentage</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
                    <td>{{ student.Name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ student.RollNo }}</td>
                    <td>{{ student.Percentage }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**data.txt**

```
[
   {
      "Name" : "Mahesh Parashar",
      "RollNo" : 101,
      "Percentage" : "80%"
   },
   {
      "Name" : "Dinkar Kad",
      "RollNo" : 201,
      "Percentage" : "70%"
   },
   {
      "Name" : "Robert",
      "RollNo" : 191,
      "Percentage" : "75%"
   },
   {
      "Name" : "Julian Joe",
      "RollNo" : 111,
      "Percentage" : "77%"
   }
]
```

Comment: what is the error, check in console

Comment: @Ali - Thanks for the idea. Found the problem after checking the console. Was missing brackets and semicolon in the controller function.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the contents of a txt file, it most likely is being interpreted as a string, so you are settings students to some string.

Instead, try:

```
$http.get(url).success(function (response) {
    $scope.students = JSON.parse(response);
});
```

Update:

Now that I think about it, shouldn't the response have a data attribute?

```
$http.get(url).success(function (response) {
    $scope.students = response.data;
});
```